# もん - meaning and when to use

Tags: meaning

What does もん mean in a sentence like the one below:

> うちの**もん**が卒業{そつぎょう}しまして

It is used like "myself" in English, to reinforce "I"? So, sort of like "I myself" graduated?
And when is it used?

Comment: Could you provide some context? Maybe some of the surrounding sentences?

Answer (score 4):

もん is a casual way of saying もの(者、物). This もん is 者. うちのもん means "a person who belongs to the speaker's own family" or "a person who is close to the speaker".